# how to find occurences of particular string in a String

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the default functionality of alert by using following piece of code

```
window.alert=function(txt)
 {
  waitOk='wait';
  setMsgBox(txt);
  btnMsgOk.focus();             
 }
```

but these functionality should be different for two different kind of messages i.e. error message and success message. so i have modified the code of setMsgBox(txt) to look for string error

```
var abc = txt;
var def=abc.match(/Error/g);
var ghi =def.length();
if(ghi==0)
{
-----
}
```

after checking conditions i will make the image visibility hidden if it's an error message.
but it's throwing an error at def function expected. please help me to fix this code

Comment: `match()` returns an array, and the `length` property of arrays is a property, not a method. You do not have to call it.

Comment: Frederic beat me to it!  He's right Also, not the best idea to override native methods like alert.  Maybe namespace it, like MyApp.alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc = txt;
var def=abc.indexOf('Error');
if(def==-1)
{
-----
}
```